# I have duplicate accounts on DIY, can they be merged?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Seems I have a different OpenID as when I first signed up. Both of these:
https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/417/hometoast

https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/1697/hometoast

are me. Do SE sites have this function available or should I continue my double life?

Answer (score 6):

The process is to change the email address on the account you want to lose so that it matches the one on the account you want to keep, then flag the accounts for moderator attention.  See [this answer on meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste/73801#73801) for details.